# JQuery fill the form but failed to be recognized

Tags: javascript, jquery, flask, flask-wtforms

I am using Flask as the backend. And I wrote a simple form with WTForm, say,

```
field = StringField('input:', validators=[Required()])
```

And I write a JQuery to fill it automatically

```
$('#theidofthefield').val('fillingin');
```

And I click the submit button in the form but it shows that the field is empty. And I check the request.form.field.data is also empty.
Hope to get a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no idea about `WTForm` but you can check if your field element has got the **name** attribute, which is required to send back to the backend code.

Your field has to be something like this:

```
<input type="text" name="thenameofthefield" id="theidofthefield" />
//-----------------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^---name attribute is required.
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to fill value is:

```
$('#theidofthefield').attr('value','filling');
```

Lets see if it works..

In case variable field is pointer to the object then..
$(field).val('dfsdf') or $(field).attr('value','filling') may work.